# Can you use admob during alfa and beta testing in google play?

Tags: android, google-play, admob

Simple question - can you use live AdMob ads (i.e. not in test mode) during alpha and beta testing in Google Play?

Comment: Its up to you, If you want to test the ads also you can.. beta/alfa is for testing purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Alpha and Beta are supposed to be a restricted rollout to a small number of users, they have no effect on admob.

Read about it in [this guide](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en).