# Native Express ads in alpha testing

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I currently have an app in alpha testing channel of Google Play Store and I want to show Native Ads in my app. Is it okay to use live native ads while app is in alpha testing. The document states

> During development and testing, use only test ads [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

Is it against Google AdMob policy to use live ads while app is in Google Play Store available to limited users(in alpha testing)? I have read developers using live ads in alpha/beta testing [Using ads in alpha/beta testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240096/can-you-use-admob-during-alfa-and-beta-testing-in-google-play)
I need to clarify this. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: if u use ad in alpha or beta test you may get some warning as google dont allow to use ad in beta/alpha testing

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Only **clicking** is against AdMob policy during development and testing time. Everything else is Ok.